# Apache passenger deploy sinatra

Tags: ruby, apache, deployment, sinatra, passenger

I am using apache and passenger. I have my app in /home/git/app/public

My sites-enbled have a file called app with this content

```
<VirtualHost *:9292>
  #ServerName www.yourhost.com
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /home/git/app/public    
  <Directory /home/git/app/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
```

My mods-enabled have:
passenger.load

```
 LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/passenger-4.0.21/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

passenger.conf

```
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/passenger-4.0.21
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
```

This paths were returned from to run:
    passenger-install-apache2-module

All paths are working.

```
$>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]
$> which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
```

error.log in apache
http://pastebin.com/u50SQJ4h

Procces running

```
root       622  0.2  1.7 118432  8600 ?        Ss   12:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k     start
root       624  0.1  0.4 223496  2064 ?        Ssl  12:55   0:00 PassengerWatchdog
root       631  0.0  0.4 503552  2424 ?        Sl   12:55   0:00 PassengerHelperAgent
nobody     639  0.0  0.9 235480  4900 ?        Sl   12:55   0:00 PassengerLoggingAgent
www-data   655  0.0  1.1 118504  5888 ?        S    12:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   657  0.0  1.0 118456  5388 ?        S    12:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   659  0.0  1.0 118456  5388 ?        S    12:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   660  0.0  1.0 118456  5388 ?        S    12:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   661  0.0  1.0 118456  5388 ?        S    12:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

When I visit IPSERVER:9292, not load. In port 80 are running normally. If I will run my app in :9292 I need to run:
    passenger start -p '9292' -e 'production' --daemon

My app has the following struct:

```
/home/git/app
    app.rb  
    config.ru  
    public  
    tmp
$> cat config.ru
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

set :environment, ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym
disable :run, :reload

require 'app.rb'

run Sinatra::Application
$> cat app.rb
get '/hi' do
   "Hello World!"
end
```

But I want my app to start with system. Any idea?

Comment: What is output for `which ruby`? Does your `config.ru` look something like the model at http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_sinatra? What does your Apache `error_log` (or Passenger log) say about loading Passenger?

Comment: Thanks for replying @kardeiz, I have updated with more information.

Comment: I am stupid, I have fixed this adding Listen 9292 to ports.conf

Comment: If you've found a solution, you might want to answer your own question.